# Draw a ring using the HTML5 canvas without the straight line

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, automatic-ref-counting, ring

I want to draw a ring with the canvas that **doesn't** have the straight black line you see when you use the below code.

```js
 var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
 var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
 //ctx.arc(x,y,radius,startAngle,endAngle, anticlockwise);  
 ctx.beginPath()
 ctx.arc(100,100,100,0,Math.PI*2,false); // outer (filled)
 ctx.arc(100,100,55,0,Math.PI*2,true); // outer (unfills it)
 ctx.fillStyle='red';
 ctx.fill();
 ctx.strokeStyle='black';
 ctx.lineWidth=1;
 ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
```

Comment: don't stroke, draw outer and inner circles separately with `arc()` with 1px width

Comment: I want to stroke both the outer circle and inner circle, as I have done. I just don't want the straight line between them.

Comment: use 2 extra paths for inner and outer borders

Comment: Reading your comment again, I think I understand what you meant now. You're saying draw the red ring but don't stroke it. Then, with a new path, draw the inner circle, stroke it, and then, with another new path, draw the outer circle, and then stroke it. Thanks very much.

Comment: Oh nevermind my previous comment, don't know what I had in mind at this early time. But if the dupe target isn't clear enough: https://jsfiddle.net/sc714rxf/ (Also don't forget the add an `@` sign when you ping someone in here).